# What is the maximal ideal used to construct the Hyperreals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm working through the AMM paper [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321645) on the construction of (a model of) the Hyperreals.  The paper gives the following sequence of arguments and definitions:

If we take the set of sequences $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, define $F$ as the set of sequences with finite support on $\mathbb{N}$ (the ones that have identically zero tails).  We know there must be a maximal ideal $M$ that contains $F$ since $F$ is a proper ideal.  We can then define a field $\mathbb{R}^* = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} / M$ by taking the quotient of the set of sequences by that maximal ideal, and we call $\mathbb{R}^*$ the Hyperreals.

Now I'm with you, that all makes sense (admittedly I didn't know every proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal, but it makes sense).  However I'm wondering what the hell $M$ actually looks like?  What are its elements?

Comment: Short answer: the statement "every proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal" depends on (or even, if I remember correctly, is equivalent to) the axiom of choice. Thus, there may not be any explicit description of $M$, and therefore of $\mathbb R^*$.

Comment: Is that a "in general you shouldn't expect such maximal ideals to have a construction" or a "... and I happen to know that in this case there is no explicit construction of said maximal ideal".

Comment: There is a description of $M$ in terms of nonprincipal ultrafilters. If you're more comfortable with ultrafilters that might qualify as a description, if you're not, it won't be very illuminating

Comment: @Max The only maximal ideals of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ that we can know to exists without the Axiom of Choice are those that contain all sequences that are zero everywhere except at the $m$th component (for a fixed $m$) -  and such a maximal ideal cannot contain $F$. I suggest you add the *Axiom of Choice* tag to your question - that will probably summon *Asaf Karagila* and I am sure we will then learn how much choice exactly the construction of $\Bbb R^*$ (equivalently, of a maximal ideal that is not of the trivial form described above, or of a non-trivial ultrafilter) requires.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Added AoC tag.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : it wasn't my question :-) and the exact amount of choice required for "one nonprincipal ultrafilter" is not relates to other principles I think, although "any infinite set has a nonprincipal ultrafilter" is a well-recognized choice principle that stands on its own (it's not related to the usual dependent or countable choice, it's strictly weaker than AC but not provable in ZF). My point was that describing $M$ in terms of an ultrafilter is useless if OP has no clue what those are (and useful if they know what they are)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

1. First off, lisyarus' comment is spot-on, that in general it can be hard to get explicit descriptions of things constructed via the axiom of choice.  However, in this particular case, there are several things that can be said...
2. At a very primitive level, the construction of the hyperreals is very much like the construction of the reals from rational numbers via Cauchy sequences.  Each point of $\mathbb{R}^*$, as defined as in your question, is an equivalence class of sequences, where two sequences are equivalent if e.g. they are identical after some finite number of terms.  By comparison, in the construction of the real numbers from rationals, two Cauchy sequences of rationals are equivalent if they get arbitrarily close and stay close for high indices (the usual Cauchy criterion).
3. A better way to get a feel for what $\mathbb{R}^*$ looks like is from carrying on the theory of nonstandard analysis, which leads to the discovery that $\mathbb{R}^*$ looks roughly like the real line, but augmented with clouds of infinitesimals around each point, and infinitely large numbers too.

As an aside, it is often true that non-standard analysis gives us a tool to understand abstract objects created by the axiom of choice.  I can't find a reference to this right now, but I know there are instances of standard constructions (i.e. not using the hyperreals) which need the axiom of choice and are somewhat hard to understand, but which can be constructed explicitly and "constructively" within the framework of non-standard analysis (i.e. using infinitesimal and infinite hyperreals).  I put "constructively" in quotes because the hyperreals require the axiom of choice for their definition, so such "constructions" are still not properly constructive, but once you've allowed yourself the possibility of non-standard numbers, then you can sometimes use them to get intuition about otherwise vague objects.

Comment: How/why do you identify $\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}/M$ with *"numbers"* ? We can construct an ordered field extension of $\Bbb{R}$ based on a (transfinite) sequence of infinitesimals and inject it in $\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}/M$ but identifying both...

Comment: @reuns Well, $\mathbb R^*$ is a field, and has an embedded copy of $\mathbb R$, so why not call them numbers? After all, isn't the whole idea of ring/field theory, in a sense, about answering the question "What *else* can we call numbers?"

Comment: Thanks, oh well.  Do you know if there are any "constructively-friendly" rigorous attempts at infinitesimals or is the axiom of choice indispensable to any project using hyperreals?

Comment: @WilliamBell The axiom of choice in necessary for the construction of the hyperreals.  However, for the reasons outlined in the last paragraph of my extended comment, you might say that this is a feature, rather than a bug.  There are other approaches to defining infinitesimals, most notably "smooth infinitesimal analysis", but it has it's own defects (which in my opinion are much worse than non-standard analysis).

Comment: @WilliamBell In general, there's no reason to expect that infinitesimals should be constructive, as infinitely small/large quantities are, almost by definition, impossible to construct in reality.  It's not clear that anything in the real world is truly infinite, but as a concept infinity can still be a useful idealization.

Comment: @Yly That's a strange (to me) intuition about constructibility, to tie it to physical possibility. For instance, it is possible to construct and say a lot about properly divergent sequences (which have a kind of claim to potential infinity), even though there's nothing guaranteeing anything of the sort is possible in reality.

Comment: @WilliamBell It's not a point I care to belabor--it's just a heuristic.  But to answer your specific proposal: With a divergent sequence, every term in the sequence is finite.  You can never write down every term in the sequence, but you can write down arbitrarily many, and finite approximations are "good enough" to e.g. distinguish between two sequences.  With an infinitesimal/infinite number, no finite approximation is "good enough".  With hyperreals defined as in your post, there are some equivalent sequences which cannot be distinguished by any finite number of terms.